# What does 'contrasting' mean. in this case of 'must draw their examples from contrasting markets'

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am asked and have to answer the question below.

> The candidate should give examples of existing restrictions on free trade that wine and spirits producers face today. Candidates must draw their examples from contrasting markets around the world.

This question is all about the drink industry but
I do not understand what implies "contrasting markets" above. 
Should I show some examples that exists as restrictions by contrasting which is of another markets? or still in the drink markets, or any other meaning?

Sorry that I am not sure this type of question is appropriate in here or not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To me it implies markets which contrast against each other (that is, different types of market), but I'm not an economist and can't give any examples to show what that means in practice.

Comment: It's like asking for opposites - sometimes, there's an obvious dimension you can use (high / low); other times, it's not clear-cut (love/hate vs apathy/hate). In your case, *contrasting markets* may be defined in the syllabus. If not, **try asking your lecturer**. It might be capitalist vs communist, protectionism vs free trade, international vs domestic, big vs small, or something else altogether.

Comment: Looks to me like "contrasting" here is just a 50 cent way of saying a 10 cent word: "different".

Comment: Maybe like this: take as examples Spain, Brazil, and China. Do not take as examples Spain, France, and Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Contrasting means showing the differences between things as opposed to comparing which shows the similarities.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contrasting

You can show the differences between markets and how some are more restrictive than others ( maybe demand higher tariffs, have qualifications that are deliberately hard to meet etc ) .

Comment: "contrasting" is being used here as an adjective, not a verb. If they'd written "by contrasting" that would mean the candidate is supposed to describe the differences.

Comment: Doesn't he still have to describe the differences anyway to arrive at a satisfactory answer? Or would that depend on the type of answer required and whether it should be in essay form? Then again I know very little about economics, so you're probably right.

Comment: The part quotes doesn't say he's supposed to describe the differences, just provide examples from different types of markets.

Comment: It's not really specific to economics. Imagine a botany exam that said "Provide examples of tree leaves, drawing examples from contrasting forests around the world."

Answer (score 0):

I think contrasting here would mean from different places, countries, various types of drink (not just wine or spirits, but breweries, alcohol etc.) markets.

Contrast actually means unrelated. For example, the room was painted with contrast colors of ink blue, bright pink and yellow.

Contrast: the state of being strikingly different from something else in juxtaposition or close association: